# using invokelater wit runnable method

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

Sorry if this question stupid but i am trying to learn java and do some tuts on Swing. On all the tuts it is demonstrated on how to use the EventQueue.invokelater Method and pass it a Runnable object and override the run Method of it.

Code of one example looks as follows:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable test = new Runnable ();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Guitest ex = new Guitest();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

While running the code n eclipse it always tells me:

```
The method invokeLater(Runnable) in the type EventQueue is not applicable 
    for the arguments (new Runnable(){})
```

Why doesnt it accept the method as argument? What am a missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument should be accepted, however the line above it, `Runnable test = new Runnable();` is invalid as `Runnable` cannot be instantiated that way.

Comment: The first `new Runnable()..` should be like the 2nd, and **define the `run()` method.**

Comment: the test object was just for testing purposes, sorry. However the argument isnt accepted even without it.

also tried that one:
      `public static void main(String[] args) {
     Runnable test = new Runnable() {
        
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Guitest ex = new Guitest();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        };`
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(test);
        
    }
still not accepting as argument.

Comment: Maybe the "official" oracle guide can help you out learning about concurrency in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html